# How to make @username reply system with flutter and firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, frontend

How will this work in the flutter side? How can I make textfield change color (to show it is clickable/tappable that redirects to user's homepage) and such that it also notifies the pinged user?

Comment: Please can you provide more information, what are you asking? You are probably asking multiple questions. Are you interest about username system, are you intered about textfield ... notifications?

Comment: This question is way too broad to answer. There are lots of things to do for the `@username` reply system. You need to break down your question into multiple smaller ones like - How to show users list when typing `@` symbol, then, how to redirect etc.

Comment: Lets start with how to make flutter side. How do I make keyboard understand what @ is and what it does when I click it given that I would be fetching these comments containing @ from firestore I guess I will be using RichText right?   @RaviSinghLodhi